# How to upgrade my Visual Studio 2012 from .NET Framework 4.5 to .NET Framework 4.7.2?

Tags: c#, .net-4.7.2

I am using a Visual Studio 2012. It looks like this when I start it:

[image: (picture of VisualStudioStartUp)]

This is the look of Visual Studio 2012 when it is finally opened:

[image: (picture of VisualStudioStartUp2)]

I am planning to make a Discord chatbot using the C# programming language. But before I will do that, I need to search on the Internet. This is the site I will use as a guide:

[image: (picture of VaporCompletePart1)]
[image: (picture of VaporCompletePart2)]

This is the link of the site (as shown on the above picture) I'm gonna use as a guide:

[(Link of VaporComplete)](https://vapor.li/showthread.php?tid=156)

Now that I have read the entire webpage, I started to follow what is written by the author of the site.

All goes well when I stumbled upon this part:

[image: (picture of VaporCompletePart1Encircled)]

The author of the website had this so-called .NET Framework 4.6.1, which I think, a foundation, or more accurately, a "clean piece of long bond paper" in my opinion, to create a Discord chatbot.

[image: (AuthorFramework pic)]

But when I tried to follow the author's way, I wasn't able to follow it because my Visual Studio 2012 has this so-called .NET Framework 4.5, and the author's got a Visual Studio 201? (I do not know the version of Visual Studio the author is using) having .NET Framework 4.6.1.

[image: (VS pic)]

When I tried to upgrade my Visual Studio 2012's .NET Framework to 4.7.2 in the belief that I could make a C# Discord chatbot while having the same interface as the author's (see below)...

[image: (AuthorFramework pic)]

...it didn't upgrade.

I still see the same .NET Framework 4.5 in my Visual Studio 2012. The upgrade didn't work even if I downloaded the .NET Framework 4.7.2 from this website and restarted my slow laptop so it can be installed.

[image: (MSWebsite pic)]

When I Googled for the solution for this upgrade problem, all they ever show was to look into this...

[image: (Solution pic)]

...implying that I needed to be very smart in order for my Visual Studio 2012 to be upgraded from .NET Framework 4.5 to .NET Framework 4.7.2.

In my Visual Studio 2012, there is a myth/belief/superstition that if I download and install a higher version .NET Framework, it will just magically appear on my Visual Studio 2012 and I just choose it in the Properties panel like this one below on my Visual Studio 2012...

[image: (Properties panel)]

...which, if I continued the process, confirms that upgrading a particular .NET Framework described in the above method is a myth because it 
doesn't work.

My question is:

> How to upgrade my Visual Studio 2012 from .NET Framework 4.5 to .NET Framework 4.7.2 smoothly, correctly, and without any concerns and problems?

Comment: You need to install the Multi Targeting pack, not just the framework for Visual Studio support. Go here, and "Developer Pack" for the version of the framework you want. https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks

Comment: You cannot create .NETCore projects in VS2012, updating to VS2017 is required.

Comment: @HansPassant oh...I can't abandon my Visual Studio 2012. Maybe I will match the author of the website's .NET Framework to 4.6.1. Is it valid too?

Comment: No need to abandon anything, installing multiple versions of VS is supported.  The issue is not caused by the framework version, you don't have the required build tools and project templates to create such a project.

Comment: @HansPassant so you mean...in order for me to make a Discord bot using c# programming language, I must use the Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: @HeckYeah: Or don't use an IDE at all. Or use VS Code. There are options, but using VS 2012 is probably not one of them.

Comment: The screen shots show a very old Visual Studio 2017 build, which mistakenly shows .NET Framework combo box for .NET Core projects. Such is already fixed in latest VS2017 build. If you do want to work on .NET Core, like others commented, you must use VS2017 or VSCode.

Comment: @LexLi If my Visual Studio 2012 cannot be used to make a Discord chatbot, I'll try using the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 or the VS Code. Thanks for helping me out....

Comment: @DaisyShipton If my Visual Studio 2012 cannot be used to make a Discord chatbot, I'll try using the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 or the VS Code. Thanks for helping me out....

Comment: @HansPassant If my Visual Studio 2012 cannot be used to make a Discord chatbot, I'll try using the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 or the VS Code. Thanks for helping me out....

Comment: @vcsjones The commenters tell me that I need to use the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 or its alternative, VSCode so I can now start making a Discord bot using C# programming language.

Comment: Well that's assuming you really need .NET 4.7.2 for Discord. It's entirely possible that's not the case, but frankly I'd recommend using the latest version of VS anyway. That way you can use all the C# 6 and 7 features, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to create .NET Core projects using Visual Studio 2012. Nowadays, platform version and Visual Studio became more separate, but it is only from Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

You must download and install the Microsoft .NET Developer Pack